# StreamWriter not flushing

Tags: c#, io, streamwriter

I want to write a file of about 10 million rows. I'm using `StreamWriter` with a using statement, however it seems that the `StreamWriter` is not flushing. Here is my code:

```
public void ExportRecords(IEnumerable<Record> records, string path)
    {
        using(TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("header");

            foreach(var record in records)
            {
                string line = "";
                //Fill line with record properties
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

At a certain line the `StreamWriter` doesn't add any rows. So where is the issue?

***EDIT***

As mentioned is the comments the code is run async.

Here is how it is:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath))
    {
        var records = _generator.GenerateData();

        _dataService.ExportRecords(records, $"{folderPath}/RECORDS.csv");
        //Just a message box
        _reporter.ReportMessage($"Generation and exportation finished");
    }
    else
    {
        IsGenerating = false;
        _reporter.ReportMessage("No output file was created");
    }

});
```

So I did put a breaking point to check if the method starts executing, and it does. I'm just indicating the the code is not stuck in generation method.

Comment: What means "at a certain line the StreamWriter doesn't add any rows"? Do you mean "when the function returns, not all lines are written" or "when I debug my code and stop inside my foreach loop I can't see the lines in my file"?

Comment: I just wait for 5 mins and chexk the out put file, with note pad, then a few minutes later I check again and no line is added

Comment: Pls check: 1) Does you function `ExportRecords()` return successfully? 2) Number of records in `records`, number of records written to file? 3) How to you call the function? Why do I ask: You function should work. I it stops, there should be an exception. If it writes only a part, it might be called inside of a Task / some async function that is not waiting for the function to complete.

Comment: Thank you for more information, the process is launched async, I'll put some more code in the question

Comment: I have to guess: You are calling `Task.Run()` inside of an object instance. Because you're not waiting for the result, directly after starting your Taks "it's all done" and the instance will be disposed. This disposes your `_reporter` instance too and so your `ExportRecords()` function will be interrupted. You should add some logging to see if this guess is true.

Comment: What type of application is it?  Task.Run() is probably not useful. Remove it and run the code synced.

Comment: @Holterman, it's WPF, running synced will cause the app to break after a certain amount of time

Comment: We still can't see how you call this,  or how you handle exceptions.

Comment: I am here because noticed that mine doesn't flush either sometimes, or rather flushes whenever it wants, even if I use StreamWriter overload that let me specify buffer size.  :-) Yes, If it's an API background processes will be terminated when API finishes request with i.e. return Ok(); Nothing can run in the background when this happens. Tested it in practice with asp.net web api (not core)

Answer (score 1):

Change temporarily the type of your application to Console Application (if it is Windows Application), and add some `Console.WriteLine` at strategic points so that you have some feedback about the progress of the procedure. Even better you could add logging to your application, using a library like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [Serilog](https://serilog.net/). It will be useful in the production phase of your application too, not only in the development/debugging phase.

Answer (score 0):

`Flush()` has to be manually called at some point if you need it in the middle of the operation, otherwise the stream will only be flushed at the end of the statement, when it is disposed.